# Stack Overflow on Property Setter

Tags: c#, properties, setter

I have an object in C# which has current property.

```
public DateTime startDate
{
    get 
    {
        string[] ymd = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[2].Split('.');
        return new DateTime(Int32.Parse(ymd[2]), Int32.Parse(ymd[1]), Int32.Parse(ymd[0])); 
    }
    set { startDate = value; }
}
```

But when I try to use the function defined as this:

```
public String Calculate(){
    if (startDate > endDate)
        return "not calculable since the end date can not be before than the start date.";

    while (startDate <= endDate)
    {
        if (startDate.DayOfWeek.ToString()[0] != 'S')
            count++;
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
    }

    return "not implemented yet";
```

Stack Overflow occurs :) Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with `DateTime`. It's a simple problem with your setter which could have been avoided by using a better naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is setting itself here, causing an infinite loop:

```
set { startDate = value; }
```

You would need a backing field to keep the value of the property, and initialise it if it hasn't been set:

```
private DateTime? _startDate;

public DateTime startDate {
  get {
    if (!_startDate.HasValue) {
      string[] ymd = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[2].Split('.');
      _startDate = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(ymd[2]), Int32.Parse(ymd[1]), Int32.Parse(ymd[0]));
    }
    return _startDate.Value;
  }
  set { _startDate = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a mistake in your setter. You're trying to assign to the same property, that's the cause of the stack overflow, as every assignment to a property is just calling it's setter.

```
set { startDate = value; }
```

Comment: Exactly. The `set` accessor calls itself _ad infinitum_.

Comment: create a class variable for start date and substitute that instead of same name as property